# Find out the average price for each model in the top5 manufacturers in terms of sales quantity and order by average price

Tags: sql-server

Find out the average price for each model in the top5 manufacturers in terms of sales quantity and order by average price.

I thought about first finding the average price of each model joining with manufacturer table
then i added a sub-query of finding top 5 manufacturer in terms of sales quantity and order by average price

```
select ft.IDModel, avg(TotalPrice) as [average price],
       sum(Quantity) as [sale quantity]
from   FACT_TRANSACTIONS as FT
       join DIM_MODEL as dm 
       on ft.IDModel=dm.IDModel
where  IDManufacturer IN
       (
            select top 5 IDManufacturer 
            from DIM_MODEL 
            where IDModel IN
            (
                 select top 5 IDModel
                 from   FACT_TRANSACTIONS 
                 group by IDModel
                 order by sum(Quantity) desc
            ) 
            group by IDManufacturer
        )
group by FT.IDModel
order by [average price];
```

Actual output:

```
IDModel average-price   sale-quantity
110      91.3636        12
108     151.0833        12
109     175.4444        12
107     185.10          15
106     236.75          14
111     285.909         11
104     503.5882        17
103     524.7142         8
102     535.1428         9
101     597.9523        33
105     633.7142        16
```

i know i am not doing it right so i request to please assist me

Comment: Please add some sample data from your both tables and then add your expected output from them.

Comment: If you want each model in the top 5 manufacturers, you don't want the 2nd TOP 5 on the innermost query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 5
Manufacturer_Name,
AVG(TOTALPRICE) AVG_RATE,
SUM(QUANTITY)   SALE_QUANTITY
FROM FACT_TRANSACTIONS T1 
                          LEFT JOIN DIM_MODEL M1
                          ON T1.IDModel=M1.IDModel
                          INNER JOIN DIM_MANUFACTURER M2
                          ON M1.IDManufacturer=M2.IDManufacturer
GROUP BY Manufacturer_Name
ORDER BY SALE_QUANTITY DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Select distinct Table_1.Manufacturer_Name, Table_1.Model_Name,  
Table_2.Total_Qauntity, Table_2.Total_Sales from   
(select  manu.Manufacturer_Name, Model.Model_Name  
from   
FACT_TRANSACTIONS AS Trans  
inner join   
DIM_MODEL as Model   
on   
Trans.IDModel = Model.IDModel  
inner join   
DIM_MANUFACTURER as Manu   
on   
Model.IDManufacturer = Manu.IDManufacturer  
group by   
manu.Manufacturer_Name, Model.Model_Name ) Table_1  
right join   
(select top 5 manu.Manufacturer_Name, sum(trans.TotalPrice) as  Total_Sales, Sum(trans.Quantity) as Total_Qauntity  
from   
FACT_TRANSACTIONS AS Trans  
inner join   
DIM_MODEL as Model   
on   
Trans.IDModel = Model.IDModel  
inner join   
DIM_MANUFACTURER as Manu   
on   
Model.IDManufacturer = Manu.IDManufacturer  
group by   
manu.Manufacturer_Name  
order by Total_Sales desc, Total_Qauntity desc  
) Table_2   
on Table_1.Manufacturer_Name = Table_2.Manufacturer_Name
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).